# Google Drive for Windows not running at startup

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a user running Windows 7 and their Google Drive sync has completely stopped running. It's not running in the systray, I can't manually restart it. I've tried rebooting the machine and redownloading and installing Google Drive for Windows. Nothing seems to get it to start again.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Any storage left?

Comment: There is 40GB left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have resolved this by uninstalling and reinstalling with the Install as Administrator option.